# Crash when assigning items to a UITabBar

Tags: swift, xcode, uitabbar

If I put an exception breakpoint (All exceptions) in Xcode, It breaks on the `tabbar.items` for some strange reason.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let tabbar = UITabBar()
    let item = UITabBarItem(title: "", image: UIImage(), selectedImage: UIImage())
    tabbar.items = [item]  // --- BREAKS HERE
    return true
}
```

However, If I create an empty project and put the same lines, it won't crash. So I figure it must be something with my project.

How do I debug this?

[image]

Comment: What is the error you see?

Comment: Can you paste your error log in your question?

Comment: I updated the answer. It doesn't crash, just breaks, which is really annoying.